# how to split a column containing pipe-separated string into two columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two split pipe-separated columns in a table
like

```
column_name
name-MARYAM BEGUM | MOHD AIJAZUR RAHMAN
fathers_name-AIJAZUR RAHMAN | MOHD HABEEB SAB
```

when i using explode split function, it producing 4 rows as I want two rows like

```
name                                              fathers name
|SYED YOUSUF                                     |JANI MIYA             |
| MOHAMMED MUBEEN UL ALI                         | MOHAMMED SHAFI UL ALI|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withColumn` to create a new column from existing column values. You can extract data from a column using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract`. You can also use combination of `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.substring` and `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.instr` functions etc. Please take a look at all the [functions available](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).

```
//lets say "column_name" has concatenated data

df.withColumn($"name", regexp_extract($"column_name", <expression to extract name>, <group index>))
df.withColumn($"father_name", regexp_extract($"column_name", <expression to extract fathers name>,<group index>))
```